# ArrayList strange behavior

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Im doing a app that takes data from a xml, put on a database, and the display this data (the name of the picture and the url) in a gridview of pictures.
I added a onitemclicklistener to get the url (from the ArrayList), and transfere to another activity, so I can transform the url to a bitmap and display in a imageview.

```
   //cursor that returns all items from databse to a arraylist
    final Cursor cursor = entry.getAllRows();

//arraylist
            names = new ArrayList<Post>();

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            //adding all database values to the arraylist
            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                names.add(new Post(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("link"))));
                cursor.moveToNext();



            }
```

now the onitemclicklistsner code:

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);

                position++;
            Post text = names.get(position);
            Log.i("POSITION", "Exeption:"+position + " " + text);

                //i.putExtra("id", text);
                //startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

Im getting the right position, but the problem is that i cannot get the corresponding url from the position.
Its not displayng a link, but displayng this:
com.example.partedoxml.Post@42b191d8
The question is how I cant get a single item position from the arraylist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is

```
names.get(position);
```

what you are trying to do is getting the Post object not the name

so in your Post Class there will be a filed named by **Name**

get that name like

**in post class create getter and setter for name**
and then in your listener write

```
String name =names.get(position).getName();
```

**or**

in your post class make name **public**

```
public String name;
```

and then in your listener

```
 String name =names.get(position).name;
```

or what you are doing

```
   Post text = names.get(position);  
   Log.i("POSITION", "Exeption:"+position + " " + text.name);
```

Comment: thanks man, I really love you, your answer was easy to understend and solved my problem.
The String urlimg was private and I changed and used your code.

Comment: Do you mind to explain why needs to be public? Knowedge is never too much

Comment: public identifier is used to access the variable or method outside the class like you did that..

Answer (score 0):

You are getting one post by index (index being you specifying in the position variable).

You need to implement `public String toString(){}` method in your Post class to see field values within the Post object.